# How to escape space in gradle script while running it on Linux OS?

Tags: java, gradle, groovy

I am running my gradle script on both windows and Linux OS.This is running fine while I run it on Windows OS.I am trying to execute the hg command to create the tag and push it to repository.Script is working fine.The issue is tag name.I apply the tag with below command which is running fine on windows OS.Gradle script is running this command.

```
commandLine "hg tag -r $hash \"Build $cbversion\"".split()
```

But the same command is throwing an error while running on Linux OS and not applying the tag with Build 1.2.3.4 name.I tried below command but no luck

```
commandLine "hg tag -r $hash Build $cbversion".split()
```

then it creates the tag with name Build only

Could someone tell me how could I overcome from this problem?

Comment: Did you try single quotes?
commandLine "hg tag -r $hash 'Build $cbversion'".split()

Comment: I tried this as well commandLine 'hg tag -r $hash Build $cbversion'.split()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is `exec`uting a process and not the shell.  You can not quote here to make it work.  [`commandLine`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Exec.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.Exec:commandLine(java.lang.Iterable)) either takes an array or iteratable as arguments.  E.g.:

```
commandLine 'hg', 'tag', '-r', hash, "Build $cbversion"
```